# Duplicate event 409 error when updating a calendar invite

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

We've been using the same process for creating a google calendar invite for a year now, and if the the calendar invite and id already exists, it will create a new one.

This code is fairly static so I am wondering if something happened on google's API that might have changed?

Here is the error returned:

```
{
  "ExceptionDetail": {
    "HelpLink": null,
    "InnerException": null,
    "Message": "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The requested identifier already exists. [409] Errors [Message[The requested identifier already exists.] Location[ - ] Reason[duplicate] Domain[global]]",
    "Type": "Google.GoogleApiException"
  },
  "ExceptionType": "Google.GoogleApiException",
  "Message": "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The requested identifier already exists. [409] Errors [Message[The requested identifier already exists.] Location[ - ] Reason[duplicate] Domain[global]]",
```

And here is the snippet of code that is creating/updating the invite

```
  service = Authentication.AuthenticateOauth();
    //Google calendar ID for calendar request. 
    EventsResource.ListRequest checkIfMade = service.Events.List(newCalendar.calendarID);
    Events events = checkIfMade.Execute();
    var hasBeenMade = false;
    foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
    {
        if (eventItem.Id == convertedID)
        {
            hasBeenMade = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hasBeenMade)
    {
        EventsResource.UpdateRequest singleEventRequest = new EventsResource.UpdateRequest(service, myEvent, newCalendar.calendarID, myEvent.Id);
        singleEventRequest.SendNotifications = true;
        singleEventRequest.Execute();
        // Debug.Print(eventLink.HtmlLink);
    }
    else
    {
        EventsResource.InsertRequest singleEventRequest = new EventsResource.InsertRequest(service, myEvent, newCalendar.calendarID);
        singleEventRequest.SendNotifications = true;
        singleEventRequest.Execute();
        //Debug.Print(eventLink.HtmlLink);
    }
}
```